# How to pass the Groovy variable to python program in Jenkinsfile

Tags: python, python-3.x, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I need to pass the groovy variable to python module.

I have tried below code but it is not working. In echo it is printing the results but when passing it to python it is taking as empty value.

```
stage('Run python code') {
steps {
    script {
        ACTIVE_CONNECTORS = sh(script: """
              test="a,b,c"
              echo "**********test value*********"
              echo \$test
              TEMP=\$(python -c \
              'import json; print(${test}); SPLIT_PUB=${data}; JSON_SPLIT_PUB=json.dumps(SPLIT_PUB); \
               JSON_SPLIT_PUB=JSON_SPLIT_PUB.replace("rename_value",$"{test}"); \
               JSON_SPLIT_PUB=JSON_SPLIT_PUB.replace("name","${params.app}");
               """.stripIndent(), returnStdout: true).trim()

                }

            }
  }
```

Comment: After interpolation your python print will look like `print(a,b,c)` that definitely raises the error. You have more errors in your code. so, think how to manage errors. If you running python just to parse json then better to use native pipeline step `readJson`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an environment variable and then call it inside the python program using os.environ. An example:

```
    stage('Test') {
        steps {
            script{
                 env.TEST = 'a,b,c'
                 ACTIVE_CONNECTORS = sh(script: """
                                                python -c "import os;\
                                                           print(os.environ['TEST'])"
                                                """.stripIndent(), returnStdout: true).trim()
                 println ACTIVE_CONNECTORS
            }
        }
    }
```